# How does Express know which Router path to use when multiple paths match?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Say there are 2 router.route(), for example:

```
router.route('/app/:id').get(funtion(req, res, next){
    console.log("id route")
});
```

and

```
router.route('/app/:username').get(funtion(req, res, next){
    console.log("user route")
});
```

When `GET /app/nsuzuki` is called, which router.route() does it use and why?

Comment: routes in express work off first match, based on the order they are loaded in.

Comment: what if i need both routes to exists? is there a way around this or can only 1 param route exist for that specific path?

Comment: If you need it like that, you have serious design flaw in your app..

Comment: Take at look at this [issue](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2206)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fully understand this, please read the documentation: http://expressjs.com/api.html#router.METHOD

## How Express Routes Capture Paths

When you use a `:param` as a part of your path, it matches everything like `/*`, and the captured value is stored in `req.params.param`.

When you have more than one rule, the first one registered is the first one checked against. It checks each call against each rule until a match is found. If you call `next()` with no values passed to it, it will look for the next match (either in the same route, or continue on into the next middleware).

So these three rules will all be run

```
var handleRoute = function(req, res, next){
   console.log(req.path + ' ' + req.params.id + ' ' + req.params.user + ' ' + req.params[0]);
   next();
}

route.route('/user/:id').get(handleRoute);
route.route('/user/:user').get(handleRoute);
route.route('/user/*').get(handleRoute);
```

When I request `/user/foobar`, I'll see the following output (and probably an error as a client because I never responded :P)

```
/user/foobar foobar undefined undefined
/user/foobar undefined foobar undefined
/user/foobar undefined undefined foobar
```

It will hit all three, but the context is different for each.

## How to Capture Path Patterns with Regular Expressions

If you want to capture separate routes for id (let's say all numbers) and user name (all letters), you can do this:

```
var handleRoute = function(tag) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(tag + ' ' + req.path + ' -> ' + req.params[0]);
    res.status(200)
      .json({
        success: 'yay!'
      });
  };
};

route.route(/^\/user\/([0-9]+)$/i)
  .get(handleRoute('id'));
route.route(/^\user\/([A-Za-z]+)$/i)
  .get(handleRoute('user'));
route.route('/user/*')
  .get(handleRoute('catch all'));
```

Note the parathesis around my capture group. Without this, `params` is empty. It auto captures with just `*` in the string because they are nice folks. I'll get the following for output when I run against the three different types.

```
id /user/123 -> 123
user /user/user -> user
catch all /user/user.1 -> user.1
```

All that explained, you're opening yourself up to some vectors for bugs to infest your system. Might want to think about your URL pattern.

Comment: thanks for the great help Chris :) I really appreciate it

Comment: No problem. Express has a lot of functionality that can be initially confusing, but it's actually just a matter of deconstructing how the pipeline works. Always fun to just implement all the examples from the docs if you want to learn how the ins and outs work.